# Enable Home and End in Gmail Compose Message window on Mac

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts, mac

I've installed [Double Command](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/) on my Mac to make the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> keys do something useful (eg: behave as they do in Windows/Linux), and this is working fine across the system. The problem is that when writing a message in Gmail, these keys don't work. Even the built-in <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> key combos don't do anything.

Is this a known issue, or have I done something strange to my settings?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem on Linux and found a related question on Google's [support forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=507e5f2a5120b488&hl=en).

This didn't work for me, but maybe it may work for you:

> The solution is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> on your Mac keyboard.

Comment: I added a key mapping in Better Touch Tool to translate Home and End to the above key strokes and it works perfectly.